# Python Hangman Graphics

Tags: python

I tried to add graphics to my code for a hangman game. The graphics didn't appeared and when you guess a letter it automatically says that the game is over. I am not sure what is wrong as I am very new to python and coding.

```
import random

Graphics=['''
------------
|         |''','''


------------
|         |         
|          O''','''


------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''','''

------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''','''


------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']


start = str(input("Welcome to Hangman!"))
failures = 0
allowed = 6
guesses_left = 6
guessed = str()
wordlist = ['kittens' , 'keen', 'right', 'square', 'baseball','soccer', 'square','house', 'safe', 'pizza', 'pasta', 'Loyola', 'cat', 'dog', 'rambler', 'Chicago', 'Pittsburgh']

def correct(guess):
    if guess in word:
        if guess not in guessed:
            print("Correct")
            return(True)
    else:
        if guess not in word and len(guess) == 1 and guess in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ':
            if guess not in guessed:
                print("Incorrect!")
                return(False)

print("Guess this word!")
print("You can input any letter from A to Z and the space key.")
wordnumber = random.randint(0, len(wordlist))
word = (wordlist[wordnumber])
guessed_letters = len(word) * ['_']
print(' '.join(guessed_letters))
while failures < allowed:
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter!"))
    if len(guess) != 1 or guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ':
        print("That is not a letter, try again.")
    if guess in guessed:
        print("You have already guessed that letter, try again.")
    iscorrect = correct(guess)
    guessed = guessed, guess
    if iscorrect == True:
        for position, letter in enumerate(word):
            if letter == guess:
                guessed_letters[position] = letter
        print(' '.join(guessed_letters))
    if iscorrect == False:
        print("Wrong!")
        failures = failures+1
        guesses_left -= 1           # Number of guesses left
        print("You have", guesses_left , "guesses left.")

    if (guessed_letters == word):
        print('''
                You have successfully guessed the word!
            ''')
    else:
        print('''
                You have lost the game! 
            ''')
    break
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are printing graphics. I'm guessing you need a 'print(Graphics[failures]) line where you print "Incorrect!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the game exists is due to a `break` that is called at the end of the very first loop. The `else` should also be based on the condition that there are no guesses left:

```
if (guessed_letters == word):
    print('''
            You have successfully guessed the word!
        ''')
    break
elif not guesses_left:
    print('''
            You have lost the game! 
        ''')
    break
```

Regarding the "graphics". This can be printed each time you get a wrong answer. And I recommend using if/else instead of two ifs here:

```
if iscorrect == True:
    for position, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == guess:
            guessed_letters[position] = letter
    print(' '.join(guessed_letters))
else:
    print("Wrong!")
    failures = failures+1
    guesses_left -= 1           # Number of guesses left
    print(Graphics[6-guesses_left])
    print("You have", guesses_left , "guesses left.")
```

`Graphics[6-guesses_left]` means go look up the index in `Graphics` that is equal to the original number of guesses (6), minus the number of remaining guesses.